# Push confirmation notification before vocal action

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to push notification from google home app before do an vocal action

example: I dev an banking application, i want to ask by vocal command " transfer 10000$ to John Doe"

at this moment, i want a notification on my phone for confirm the transaction

someone knows about which function use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Actions on Google platform that will do this directly, although you have a few potential ways to approach this.

As part of the conversation, you can confirm if they are talking to you through a mobile device. If they aren't, [you can prompt them to continue the conversation there](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations). Once they are on a mobile device, you can send a card that links to a URL which will let them authorize the transaction.

You can also use something like FCM to send the notification to their mobile platform when they reach that stage in the conversation. The notification would take them to your app or website to authorize the transaction.